# Defining right condition to check equality of integer fields

Tags: python, django

Sorry maybe my title is not so clear but i have no idea how to write it.

I have a Tournament model that saves the results of matches like:

```
class Tournament(model.Model):
    team_1_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
    team_2_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
    team_1_point = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
    team_2_point = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default=0)

    @receiver(pre_save, sender='tournament.Tournament')
    def my_callback(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
        if instance.team_1_score > instance.team_2_score:
            instance.team_1_point += 2
        elif instance.team_2_score > instance.team_1_score:
            instance.team_2_point += 2
        elif instance.team_2_score == instance.team_1_score:
            instance.team_2_point += 1
            instance.team_1_point += 1
```

And I created `pre_save` method that should automatically update of `team_1_point` and `team_2_point`values. But the problem is that my `default` value is set to `0` and of course my `pre_save` method gives 1 point to both teams.

Could you help me to make such an algorithm that will work correctly? Even if i set `default` to `""` or just leave it, it means they are equal and my method will give point anyway.

Comment: maybe use a boolean to check if it is first pass? If it is first pass, change it to false and return, then do your calculation only in the false statement

Comment: Yes it seems that something like this, can you give me link for this method that checks first pass or not?

Comment: I think i need something like `if field value none set point to 0 elif greater or equal to zero and equal to another field value set value to 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this snippet,

```
def my_callback(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not (instance.team_1_score == instance.team_2_score == 0):  # change is here <<<<
        if instance.team_1_score > instance.team_2_score:
            instance.team_1_point += 2
        elif instance.team_2_score > instance.team_1_score:
            instance.team_2_point += 2
        elif instance.team_2_score == instance.team_1_score:
            instance.team_2_point += 1
            instance.team_1_point += 1
```

**EDIT-1**

change `if` condion in my answer as below,

```
if not (instance.team_1_score is None and instance.team_2_score is None):
    #do above
```

Then chnage your `default` value in `models.py` to `None`

Comment: The matter is that the match can end with a score of 0 0 and this in turn means that it ended with an equal score, which gives each team 1 point.

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy, you just declare a global variable `x = True`, then in your `my_callback` is something like

```
if x:
    x = False
    return

if instance.team_1_score > instance.team_2_score:
        instance.team_1_point += 2
elif instance.team_2_score > instance.team_1_score:
    instance.team_2_point += 2
elif instance.team_2_score == instance.team_1_score:
    instance.team_2_point += 1
    instance.team_1_point += 1
```

Comment: yet I think this is not the most correct option for me. what if the user accidentally saved the page? He will not be able to return the changes. And it will add points to both teams

Comment: Not too sure what you are talking about